# DateTime calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have been getting an annoying issues. I have two datetime variables. Date of employment and termination date. I need to get the number of days work. termindation date - date of employment.
how do i go about getting this?

```
DateTime empDate = int.Parse((employeeEmploy.ElementAt(i).dateofEmpl).GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

DateTime terminDate = int.Parse((employeeEmploy.ElementAt(i).terminDate ).GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

int? dWorked = terminDate - empDate;
```

I tried that but that didnt work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you get a popup saying "this does not work!"?

Comment: If the guy didn't work weekends and holidays, you might want to check for workdays instead of taking the difference in days between start and termination of contract.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes. a pop up came up and says "This doesnt work". Anymore questions?

Comment: @Dineshp Ahh, you must be on the grumpy.NET platform. No further questions.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you're trying to deal with `DateTime` values - so you shouldn't be using `int.Parse` to start with. Use `DateTime.ParseExact`. Once you've got two `DateTime` values, you can use subtraction to get a `TimeSpan`, and then compute the total days from that:

```
DateTime employmentDate = ...;
DateTime terminationDate = ...;

TimeSpan employmentDuration = terminationDate - employmentDate;
int days = (int) employmentDuration.TotalDays;
```

Personally I'd actually use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project to do all of this, mind you:

```
private static LocalDatePattern TextPattern = 
     LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("yyyyMMdd");

...
LocalDate employmentDate = TextPattern.Parse(...).Value;
LocalDate terminationDate = TextPattern.Parse(...).Value;
int days = Period.Between(employmentDate, terminationDate, PeriodUnits.Days)
                 .Days;
```

Comment: im using linq to entity and my data types can be nullable. So i have things like DateTime? . With that in place, Timespan would give an error. Any work around?

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting DateTime objects produces [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx). So, use `TimeSpan.TotalDays` to get total days count between two dates:

```
int dWorked = (terminDate - empDate).TotalDays;
```

**UPDATE:** For LINQ to Enitites use [EntityFunctions.DiffDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412615.aspx) method, which calculates days between two nullable dates:

```
from x in context.Foo
select EntityFunctions.DiffDays(x.FromDate, x.ToDate)
```

Comment: how would you handle this is the datatype value .. DateTime is ... DateTime?

Comment: i am using linq to entity and they can have null values. so i declare them as DateTime? empDate and DateTime? terminDate . When i use your code above, i get an error concerning null values.

Answer (score 0):

try something along the lines of

```
var numDays = (terminDate - empDate ).TotalDays;
dworked = (int)Math.Round(numDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily substract the two Datetimes which gets you a TimeSpan!

```
        DateTime employmentDate = new DateTime(2013,03,8);
        DateTime terminationDate = new DateTime(2013,03,11);

        TimeSpan days = terminationDate - employmentDate;
        Console.WriteLine("Days: " + days.TotalDays); //Result: "Days: 3"
```